# R: More efficiently perform bootstrap given my data structure

Tags: r, loops, join

I have two matrices (mat1 and mat2). The factors in mat1 can take any of the associated values in mat2. I would like to generate n samples of values, for each element in a given row, sum the results, and calculate quantiles. Here is my working code, but I suspect this to be poorly constructed.

```
set.seed(123)

#mat1 contains selections (each row is a different group)
mat1 <- matrix(1:12, nrow=4, ncol=3)
colnames(mat1) <- letters[24:26]

#mat2 contains the possible values associated with the selections in mat1
mat2 <- cbind(rep(1:12, 2), rnorm(24))
colnames(mat2) <- c('factor', 'value')

#user specified number of samples
n <- 10

#vals and qts are set up as dummy matrices
vals <- matrix(rep(1:3, n), nrow=n, ncol=3, byrow=TRUE)
colnames(vals) <- letters[24:26]

qts <- matrix(rep(1:5, nrow(mat1)), nrow=nrow(mat1), ncol=5, byrow=TRUE)
colnames(qts) <- c('0%','25%','50%','75%','100%')

#iterate through each 'cell' of mat1 sampling possible values from mat2
for (i in 1:nrow(mat1)){
  for (j in 1:3){
    z <- mat1[i,j]
    pos_vals <- mat2[,2][mat2[,1]==z]
    vals[,j] <- sample(pos_vals, n, replace=TRUE)
  }
  qts[i,] <- quantile(rowSums(vals), probs = seq(0, 1, by= 0.25))
}

final <- cbind(mat1, qts)
final
```

Comment: Will the rows of  `mat1` always define a partitioning of the possible values in `mat2`? In other words, could a value appear more than once in `mat1`?

Comment: @Joran, in my actual dataset, values will indeed show up more than once in mat1.

Comment: Well drat, I thought I had a nice alternative for you, but I guess not. :(

Comment: I should clarify, a value can show up more than once in mat1 but not on the same row, in case that makes a difference.

Comment: @RyanCastner: Please stop repeating the inaccurate claim that R for-loops are inherently inefficient. The `*apply` family of functions are no more efficient than a for-loop with the same interior process. It is true that a vectorized approach (if one can be found) would be more efficient, but the use of `apply` does not constitute "vectorization" as the term is used in R discussions.

Comment: @drumminactuary: You should clarify questions using the edit feature. I find that clear natural language descriptions are more likely to yield an efficient solution than reading Fortran-like code. In your current description I cannot tell which matrix is being referred to when you talk about "elements in a row".  A nice working example with sufficient complexity to illustrate "edge cases" will often prompt more rapid satisfactory responses.

Comment: @42- thanks, due to said repeating I had believed that claim, did some system.time comparisons of for loops and apply functions and got similar times, sometimes better with for loops